# mysql real escape string how to use it

Tags: php, mysql

how would i add `mysql_real_escape_string()` function to the `$password_md5` and `$username` ? help would be appreciated

```
$query="UPDATE `users` SET `password` = '$password_md5' WHERE `username` = '$username'";
```

can some body give me the script for that please i forgot how to to it.
a example would really help me out

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i am trying to update my password field 
i just need to know how can i add mysql_real_escape_string function in my query
can i get a example on my query

Comment: @kunz you got some answers, if I was you I will switch off to mysqli or pdo, future wise it is worth it for your project.

Comment: Seriously, have you ever read the manual? The [example provided in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is exactly what you are asking for >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query="UPDATE users SET password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($password_md5)."' WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'";
```

Comment: Thanks Alot 
really appreciate your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password_md5= mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
$query="UPDATE `users` SET `password` = '$password_md5' WHERE `username` = '$username'";
```